# Make event for any panel c#

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a matrix of panels[image: matrix of panels] (maybe will change for Picture Boxes in the future), and what i want is that every time i press one of the panels after pressing the button on the toolbox it will change it's background to a certain picture.

Right now what i have is:

```
private void EtapaInicial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EtapaInicialWasClicked = true;
    }

    private void panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (EtapaInicialWasClicked)
        {
            panel1.BackgroundImage = Symbols.EtapaInicialbm;
            EtapaInicialWasClicked = false;
        }
    }
```

What I would like to change was the panel1 to make it work for every panel (otherwise it will only change panel1 independently of the panel i've clicked), is that possible?

Comment: `((Panel)sender).BackgroundImage = Symbols.EtapaInicialbm;`  Wire up all your panels to use that same `panel_Click` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
private void EtapaInicial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 => EtapaInicialWasClicked =  true;

private void panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (EtapaInicialWasClicked)
    {
        (sender as Panel).BackgroundImage = Symbols.EtapaInicialbm;
        EtapaInicialWasClicked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @J.Pinto glad if helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You have to loop through each panel 
and assign the same event handler but you have to make some changes in the event handler itself

```
foreach(var p in allPanels)
{
    p.Click += panel_Click;
}
```

Then change your event handler like this

```
private void panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var p = (Panel)sender;
        if (EtapaInicialWasClicked)
        {
            p .BackgroundImage = Symbols.EtapaInicialbm;
            EtapaInicialWasClicked = false;
        }
    }
```

Remember the `sender` argument contains reference to the actual control that initiated the event but you have to cast it first in order to use it.

However if you want to store more data for the event you've just handled you can use the `panel.Tag` property. This can be used to store `EtapaInicialWasClicked` for example